# Repeated Measures Two-Way Anova using Two Different Lists

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have a sequence of data from individual trials from the same subject in a dataframe. On average there are 5 repeats however this cannot be guaranteed. The (relevant) data collected are Position and Torque. For any one Position in the dataset, there may be multiple measures of Torque. I can `split(df,df[,2])` the dataframe by Position and the data becomes segmented by position. Consider the following List returned by `split()`:

```
> left
$`1`
      Time Position   Torque     Speed
76   2.950        1 14.62956  3.569444
225  6.130        1 10.36333  8.500000
373  9.215        1  7.12305 10.937500
521 12.285        1 11.27850  7.187500

$`2`
      Time Position   Torque    Speed
77   3.025        2 25.40508 17.15625
226  6.165        2 19.96992 20.60938
374  9.245        2 18.78390 31.10938
522 12.325        2 22.23847 22.43750
668 15.205        2 15.26112 24.60938

etc.

> right
$`1`
     Time Position Torque   Speed
413 8.625        1 6.1888 12.1875

$`2`
        Time Position   Torque      Speed
85   2.25400        2 15.85419  0.5541667
249  5.36500        2 10.13364  3.0703125
414  8.65000        2 17.19360 29.0833333
578 11.77500        2 31.63147 14.0625000
744 15.00571        2 23.93116 13.1785714

etc.
```

I have two groups of data like this that I want to compare, where each element of the list contains repeated measures of the same position. I want to be able to perform a two-way ANOVA on the data to test for interaction within each list on the variables `Time, Position, Torque, Speed`, and between each list: `left, right` to test for significant differences at a given position.

I have tried just about everything and can't seem to figure out a way to get these two datasets passed to `aov()` or any other ANOVA function for analysis. From my reading so far, I'll need a way to gracefully deal with variable sample numbers, and for converting the data to a type that plays well with the ANOVA functions.

Any insight you may have here would be welcome!!